# Paypal recurring payment IPN messages

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm unsure as to what IPN messages I should be expecting when a recurring payment is setup through the Express Checkout API.

The period is three months with the first three months free.
When the customer signs up, I expect an IPN message with transaction type (`txn_type`) `recurring_payment_profile_created`.
After three months, I expect a message with `txn_type = recurring_payment` and a `payment_status`. As far as I can tell, I should not be receiving one of these until *after* the end of the trial period.

But what message will I receive when a customer *cancels* the recurring payment? The only likely candidate for `txn_type` I can see is `subscr_cancel`, but this is listed with other `subscr_x` types, and I understand that subscriptions are distinct from recurring payments.

Will I receive an IPN with `txn_type = subscr_cancel` when a customer cancels are recurring payment, or will I receive something else (and if so, what will I receive)?

Answer (score 0):

You will receive an IPN for the profile creation when the user signs up.  You will also receive an IPN for each recurring payment when they are processed.  When the profile is cancelled, you will receive another IPN for this.  You will get an IPN with `txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel`.

Comment: This isn't listed in their IPN variable reference. Is that just incomplete?

Comment: According to the Paypal documentation, the value passed for the variable 'txn_type' for a cancelled subscription is 'subscr_cancel'. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: I believe that 'recurring_payment_profile_cancel' is part of a Wordpress Paypal plugin, not an IPN notification. http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-framework/

Comment: As I said, my understanding was that subscriptions and recurring payments are distinct, so the fact that subscr_cancel refers to cancellation of a subscription isn't necessarily relevant.